# Python - Writing file to a directory built by user input

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, we have a script that has some raw inputs at the beginning.  Typically the script will run and create the new files right in the same directory. I'm trying to get it to use one of the inputs to create a new directory and build the files in that directory.

```
import os
import sys
import socket
import struct

ri_name_input = raw_input("Enter the Name: ")

path = ri_name_input
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)
```

The script itself reads from some template files and then builds what we're looking for off those template files into a new file.

```
with open('derp_s1_template.txt') as infile, open(path, 'derp_s1_config.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        for src, target in repl_derp_s1.iteritems():
            line = line.replace(src, target)
        outfile.write(line)
```

The trouble is, when I run this, it correctly creates the directory (which, I noticed the permissions are a bit wonky, but I'll have to work on that) it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new_derper-2.py", line 260, in <module>
    with open('derp_s1_template.txt') as infile, open(path, 'derp_s1_config.txt', 'w') as outfile:
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Any suggestions as to where I should be looking?

Comment: `open(path, 'derp_s1_config.txt', 'w')` is incorrect.  Do `open(os.path.join(path, 'derp_s1_config.txt'), 'w')`. When `open()` gets three arguments the third argument is an integer for `buffering`: "The optional buffering argument specifies the file’s desired buffer size: 0 means unbuffered, 1 means line buffered, any other positive value means use a buffer of (approximately) that size (in bytes)."

Comment: That was it!!!  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

The `open()` function doesn't take a separate path and filename, it only takes a path to a file. You need to combine the path and filename into a single string.

```
import os

with open(os.path.join(path, 'derp_s1_config.txt'), 'w'):
    # ...
```

The error you're getting is because the 3rd optional argument in [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) is used for specifying buffer size and expects an integer. Since you were originally specifying three arguments, it was trying to use `'w'` for the buffer size, which is a type mismatch.